# Frequency analysis : relation between FFT size and sampling

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, audio

I am currently trying to perform an experiment given an audio signal. I am therefore sampling the audio frequency range (0 to 22kHz) with a 48k sampling rate.

When performing a FFT on my signal, I had the following question :

- Is it equivalent to have a very small FFT size (for example 256), producing a 172 Hz resolution on my signal, in comparison with having a large FFT size (in a way more bars..) and performing a mean on my resulting frequencies in order to bring the number of bars down?

Comment: The bin width of the fft is Sampling Frequency/number of samples (Fs/N). Larger fft will help you resolve more.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not equivalent. Taking a larger FFT means you are using more time domain samples (unless you zero pad), in which case you have introduced new information compared to a smaller FFT size